# sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 6, and there are 5 supplied

Tags: sqlite

I really do not understand what am I doing wrong. My table is:

```
conn.execute('''CREATE TABLE USERS
       (EMAIL           TEXT    NOT NULL,
       PASSWORD         TEXT    NOT NULL,
       FIRST_NAME       TEXT    NOT NULL,
       LAST_NAME        TEXT    NOT NULL,
       DATE             TEXT    NOT NULL,
       SEX              TEXT    NOT NULL);''')
```

and when I am trying to insert to the table:

```
conn.executemany("INSERT INTO USERS VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", [email, password, first_name, last_name, date, sex])
```

I get this error:

```
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 6, and there are 5 supplied.
```

if I add a question the error is the same but now:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: table USERS has 6 columns but 7 values were supplied
```

if I add only a comma without a question mark the error is different:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: near ")": syntax error
```

the variables value are:

```
    email=str(myapp.register_email.text())
    print email
    first_name=str(myapp.first_name.text())
    print first_name
    last_name=str(myapp.last_name.text())
    print last_name
    date=str(myapp.date.text())
    print date
    password="nht"
    print password
    sex=str(myapp.sex.currentText())
    print sex
```

I am really getting insane here cant figure out the problem

Comment: Please, can you show us the content of the variables that you are trying to insert?

Comment: I updated it. Im using pyqt if it helps, I print the values to see they are valid

Comment: What is the result of: 
`len([email, password, first_name, last_name, date, sex])`?

Comment: What do you mean by what is the result? I did not understand.

Comment: I would like to see the length of the insert query list, is it 5 or is it 6?

Comment: Last hint, try to assign your list to a variable: `insertValues = [email, password, first_name, last_name, date, sex]` and then use the new variable to assign to insert the entry: `conn.executemany("INSERT INTO USERS VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", insertValues)`

Comment: Already done that. Same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by the [Python doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html), the `executemany()` method requires a tuple of values. Therefore I suggest you to insert the new entry by using the following code:

```
conn.executemany("INSERT INTO USERS VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", [(email, password, first_name, last_name, date, sex)]
```

Comment: Thank you! It work!

Comment: You are welcome ;) thanks to the python doc!